# What does idx mean in idx.js

Tags: javascript

I've been using the `idx` library to safely access chained properties in javascript. Its got me thinking

### What does this idx acronym mean?

It's a little ambiguous and would suggest `index` or `internet data exchange`. When it returns values or `null`.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/idx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the link you provided:

**idx is a utility function for traversing properties on objects and arrays.**

This implies it is short for **index**.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you're right I find it implies index also. But it returns values or `null` which is why I find the name ambiguous.